# TDS Endless waves of Rebel Spies?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

In what has to be the furthest from complaining I can be, I noticed recently that I am getting almost exclusively Rebels arriving at my Death Star.... As in, as soon as I catch one, another comes in. Now, in the past two hours, I've taken in over seventy Imperial Bux... my question is, does anyone know what may have caused this. I don't believe in cheating, but I am also not opposed to getting a fun bonus every now and then...

Update: The massive influx ended after about a day and a half. To answer questions, no, I hadn't ignored the game, however, I noticed I was getting Rebels at what had probably been a slower pace than most (usually only one or two every six hours or so, playing in thirty minute increments).

I had the third elevator upgrade at the time, and now (because of the bux earned) have the final elevator.

I now get Rebels randomly, sometimes one after another, sometimes one with another following about 15 mins later or so.

Comment: I had this happen with Lando. He arrived 7 times in a row. I had 16 levels, and I left the game for a while. I also had not upgraded my elevator. So, maybe the game was trying to help. I don't know. A couple of times he escaped, but, I could not see a reason why, since I had found him immediately after pressing the blue button.

Comment: The speed by which you find them seems to have no bearing on whether they escape or not. And, escaping is a good thing because it gives you 2 Bux instead of 1.

Comment: I've observed a sharp increase in the frequency of rebel and find the bitizen events too. My spouse has also. We both have Android phones.

Comment: Same here (iOS). I didn't count, how much time it took, but I certainly made more than 70 bux last night. And day after that night it is still happening. Quite annoying, I'd say. I have 58 levels, so finding them isn't easy. And it's hard to stop yourself from doing it, too, despite the fact that I still need to fill 1,5 residential levels...

Comment: Did u guys ignore your Death Star over the holidays or anything? I'm just wondering if this is backlog.

Comment: I live in a different timezone, for me it was happening from the night of the 2th till 4th. I can't say I'm a very active player - I mostly was only stocking levels, and I was catching spies, if they showed up. But I didn't open the app less than 5 times a day. Of course, I started hunting spies actively when this started. Now there are a bit less bux quests than two days ago, but they still appear once in five minutes or less, which is more frequent, than in last year. (sorry for my English)

Comment: I get Lando over and over again too. And like others I am all of the sudden getting a high rate of both rebel spies and deliveries. I have all the levels and I'm trying to get Darth Vader to pop for a scene unlock. Instead I seem to get Lando and Bespin Leia over and over. It's annoying.

Comment: Well, no, I take my words back: they appear muuch more frequently, than once in five minutes. Also I just saw Luke hanging out on of the levels while I was looking for Lando. I thought it was the next quest, which has already appeared (the icon already was on the bottom of my screen), but the next quest was to find Chewie, and Luke disappeared.

Comment: The bitizens seem to unlock in the same order for everyone. I have played the game for nearly 2 months without unlocking Darth Vader. And, I still have a number of species to unlock. I think they unlock on their own time regardless of the missions.

Comment: If this was played over the holidays, and turned out not to be a backlog, it could be an event/happy new year from the developers giving out free cash, but making you earn it.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I'd tell you that this is random chance. But 70 in an hour points to some random bug in your favor. Keep playing and let us know if it changes.

I can say, though, that I have seen a large number of these missions in a row when I've put down the game for a while. It seems they build up over time, and if you don't play they come out all at once.

This seems harmless.  My only concern would be that if it is not progressing past a certain point, things may not be unlocking.  But, if everything else seems normal, sit back and enjoy the Bux before your eyes get blurry from searching!

Answer (score 2):

I have an Android phone and got the same increased frequency of rebels (which has now ceased).  In the last few days I managed to collect about 250 additional bux.  I think this was some sort of promotion/bonus because I got two notifications from TDS related to rebel spies during this time period.  I think the first was something like "We have detected a nest of rebel spies, keep on the lookout."  The increase in rebels occurred shortly after this.  Then a day or two later the second notification said something like, "We have uncovered the rebels hiding place, watch for an influx of spies." To answer the question raised in some of the other comments: I didn't ignore TDS during the holidays.  I played less but still checked in multiple times per day.

Comment: After my answer above I started getting more spies again so I guess there was just a lull. Yesterday I got another notification that was something like, "Keep finding rebel spies for special rewards".  Just now I got: "The Rebels are retreating! Last chance to catch spies before they're gone."  Sure sounds like a limited time bonus opportunity to me.

Comment: And today's notification: "Imperial Tech Notification: Rebel spy breach will be fixed by end of day. Stay on..."  I think it was truncated because they don't properly use expanding notifications but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a help to get the 140 bucks needed to get the holiday Boba Fett and Panna City medicines/pharmacy. We only have three days left to get them both.

Comment: This seems unlikely. They would more likely give many decorator droids instead.

Answer (score -1):

I think its a kind of Holidayevent - Like in MMORPGs, where you earn more xp at Halloween etc.

Its hard to stop, easy earned Bux - but a lot of time lost :)

Comment: That is wild conjecture at best.